# Why is my inductance and resonance frequency values of my Planar pcb simulation in COMSOL varying from the TI webench calculations?

Tags: pcb, coil, induction, planar-inductor, comsol

I am designing a planar pcb inductive sensor. I designed a simple planar inductive coil having 10 turns with each turn having 0.1 mm width and 0.1 mm gap between them. The coil is pretty small just 10 mm in size. I ran the numbers on TI webench and ran a simulation of this design on COMSOL. What I notice is that the inductance values do not match, the TI webench gives an inductance value of 1.3 uH while the COMSOL sim value is 600 nH. Also it seems like my inductor is acting like a capacitor the Induction vs Frequency plots show the characteristic graph of a inductor past its resonance, with the resonance being at some very low frequency even below 1 kHz. The TI webench calculated the SRF to be at 74 MHz. I am wondering why am I seeing such differences in results.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Resonance below 1 kHz is going to be the standout problem but, I can't tell you why. Maybe your dimension units were metres instead of mm.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be the case the dimensions are correct.